# FlashList layout animation bug React Native

Tags: react-native, flash-list

I'm developing a chat application that use inverted `FlashList` to render messages and I want to animate the layout once a new message is sent, but I'm having some problems.

> [Expo Snak](https://snack.expo.dev/@pietroputelli/312df3)

> [Bug Report on Github](https://github.com/Shopify/flash-list/issues/767)

Once I add a new message to the list, when user press on button "Send" I want to add a new message and perform a layout animation, here's a snippet of the button callback:

```
setMessages([{ content: message }, ...messages]);

listRef.current?.prepareForLayoutAnimationRender();
LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut);
```

Comment: Can I ask, why invert it? The other way is pretty standard.

Comment: It's inverted because it's better to handle, I mean I add the messages at the bottom that is the top of the inverted, it's a standard idea for implementing chat.